# Dynamically Combining Rectangles

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to combine two rectangles that I need to create dynamically but I can't figure out how to draw them using `.Data` and I don't know how to convert from `Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` to `Windows.Media.Geometry`.

```
Rectangle Cross1 = new Rectangle();
Cross1.Margin = new Thickness(465, -140, 0, 0);
Cross1.Height = 110;
Cross1.Width = 15;
Cross1.RenderTransform = rotateTransform1;

Rectangle Cross2 = new Rectangle();
Cross2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
Cross2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
Cross2.Margin = new Thickness(362, -103, 0, 0);
Cross2.Height = 110;
Cross2.Width = 15;
Cross2.RenderTransform = rotateTransform2;

CombinedGeometry c1 = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Union, Cross1, Cross2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CombinedGeometry class only works with other System.Windows.Media.Geometry objects, not System.Windows.Shapes. You need to use the equivalent RectangleGeometry class instead.

Something such as:

```
RectangleGeometry Cross1 = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 15, 110));
Cross1.Transform = rotateTransform1;
RectangleGeometry Cross2 = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 15, 110));
Cross2.Transform  = rotateTransform2;
CombinedGeometry c1 = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Union, Cross1, Cross2);
```